# Bluetooth Transmitting Legacy Name

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on an [mbed](http://developer.mbed.org) powered Bluetooth Low Energy project. I have been developing various GATT services, however, I have now found my project has got "stuck" on a previous service. What ever program I download onto the device, a Service is broadcast with the name "HRM_SEC". I have repeatedly changed the name from this.

I have installed known working examples of default Heart Rate Monitor Example. I have installed blank programs without bluetooth service definition etc.

However, the name of this prior service is persisting.

I have reinstalled my ios app - LightBlue - incase it was a casheing thing. By reinstalled I mean deleted and then downloaded from app store.

I can't connect to these services. New programs are being installed, as I am getting the expected serial feedback.

Why is this happening and What can I do?

I have just tried using the LightBlue app on a different iPhone and I am getting the expected behaviour. How can I purge the stored data from the LightBlue app. I have tried deleting it, then doing a reset (holing lock and home button), then when it has rebooted I re-downloaded the app from the app store. What else can I do to clear which ever info is being stored by LightBlue?

This seems to be an underlying iOS issue, as my other apps are also now using this legacy name. I have tried disabling and then enabling Bluetooth, but this hasn't worked. Any other ideas?

I have submitted an iOS bug report. This is really annoying, as I cannot use my iPhone to test an app I am working on. Any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: I have had similar experiences (sorry to not have all the details at ready recall). It appears that iOS remembers data associated with a previously detected bluetooth mac address. What I did to make iOS "forget" is to delete my app from the iPhone and then download it again via Xcode. You say that you "reinstalled" - did you actually do a delete?

Comment: @RobertVaessen Yes, deleted and reinstalled from App Store?